# How dataTransfer clearData / setData in IE 10 Standard mode being utilized?

Tags: internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, data-transfer

Good Day!

I am encountering issue on implementing drag and drop and IE 10 standard mode.

The scenario is like below:

I dragged a table element and add it during ondragstart on dataTransfer via setData("Text",value).
On drop action, i edit the value using setData("Text",value+othervalue) again.

Above works fine in IE 10 compatibility mode IE5Quiks, but not in IE10 Standard mode quirks

I also tried to clear the data first before setting a new one using clearData()/clearData("Text") but to no avail.

Can someone explain how data transfer works for this scenario, or what is the difference on javascirpt implementation why it is not working in ie 10 standard mode?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around for this issue.

I created a global variable in javascript and then use it as data holder instead of dataTransfer API of IE 10 which seems to be buggy at the moment.

Thanks